# Localized strings (Android) took too much memory

Tags: android, memory, localization, resources

Good day,
  I've quite big project currently localized to 21 languages where one language has around 9000 words! This is not so interesting, but

- compiled and started application with all these resources, took after start around **11 MB** in memory (simply measured by `Debug.getNativeHeapSize()`)
- when I remove 20 languages and keep only default one, it has after start only **7.5 MB**

Because biggest problem of my app are devices with low memory available for a single process (mainly older devices with 2.X android), this is very serious question for me.

So here comes two questions, hope that someone will have any useful suggestion

1. I expect that Android loads only required resources, so how it's possible that these additional languages makes so huge difference, when in memory should be in worst case just list of available resources
2. if there is not any explanation for point 1., is there any way to precompile resources into separate packages and download them on request? For example in some starting activity where user select language he wants to use?

any suggestions are more then welcome. Thanks

Comment: Use MAT to determine precisely where the difference in memory lies.

Comment: for my very big surprise, both version show exactly same results - http://tinypic.com/r/2ptuzxw/5 - so seems that Debug.getNativeHeapSize() is not best method to check amount of currently occupied memory. Thank you for good point ... how may I accept you answer if it's "just" a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memory measurement on Android is reminiscent of a portion of [Zork](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zork): a maze of twisty little passages, all alike.

If your concerns are stuff in the VM, the best way to try to get answers (IMHO) is to use [MAT](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). Particularly on Android 3.0 and higher, if you are allocating memory in the SDK, it should show up here.

For a more thorough discussion of non-MAT ways of measuring memory usage, and their pitfalls, I recommend [Dianne Hackborn's epic answer on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813).